# Convert Amount in indian currency with space after symbol | PHP 8

Tags: php, php-8

I want a Amount to be converted in **Indian currency with the symbol and space** after symbol

for example **12389** to be converted as  **₹ 12,389.00 or ₹ 12,389**

please note : number_format will not work in my case of PHP 8

I tried below

```
$fmt = new \NumberFormatter( 'en_IN', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
$amount = 12389;
$amount = $fmt->formatCurrency($amount, "INR");// exit();
 
output : ₹10,990.00
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://3v4l.org/tIvWo

Comment: correct but in postman response space is not showing

Comment: _"but in postman response space is not showing"_ - the "space" is not a normal space character, but a non-breaking space character (which makes sense, you usually don't want currency symbol and amount to break into multiple lines) - so I am guessing that perhaps Postman simply has a problem with displaying that correctly?

Comment: working correct in my environment... it must be affected by any other lines of code.. it is showing the expected result